# MySQL Workbench has stopped working

Tags: mysql, workbench, crash

I am getting this error everytime i am opening my MySQL workbench 6.3.10

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: MySQLWorkbench.exe
  Application Version:  6.3.10.0
  Application Timestamp:    5a04824f
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18666
  Fault Module Timestamp:   58f33794
  Exception Code:   e0434352
  Exception Offset: 00000000000095fc
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: f18a
  Additional Information 2: f18a865cd1cc89894e9d42aca5526392
  Additional Information 3: 70ea
  Additional Information 4: 70eab7791b8b5af301ad471c2f1430a8

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I have searched a lot but still not able to solve this problem. Any Solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution for this was installing 
`Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013`
and MySQL workbench 6.3.10 works fine.